# How do I use autocrop with a complex function for catalog_apply()?

Tags: lidr

In the case of a complex function, I would like to try the autocrop option, instead of crop inside the function, to resize output from catalog_apply() to the chunk size. In the code below, the commented-out code works, but the autocrop option doesn't.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# How to crop raster chunks?
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(terra)
library(lidR)

setwd("D:/Temp")
interpolationMethod <- tin('', extrapolate = knnidw(k = 10, p = 2, rmax = 50))

sampleLAS <- readLAS(system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR"))
sampleLAS$Classification[sampleLAS$Classification == 1L] <- 4L # veg was misclassified as 1's. change to 4
# plot(sampleLAS, color = "Classification")

sampleLASNorm <- normalize_height(sampleLAS, algorithm = interpolationMethod, na.rm = TRUE, use_class = c(2L, 9L))
writeLAS(sampleLASNorm, "MixedConiferNorm.las", index = TRUE)
ctgNorm <- readLAScatalog("MixedConiferNorm.las")

ctgNorm@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE

makeCHM_function = function(chunk) {
  las = readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las))
    return(NULL)
  vegetation <- filter_poi(las, (Classification == 3L | Classification == 4L | Classification == 5L) & Z > 0)
  if (is.empty(vegetation))
    return(NULL)
  if (npoints(vegetation) < 3)
    return(NULL)
  chmPitFree <- rasterize_canopy(las, 1, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15), max_edge = c(3, 1.5), subcircle = 0.15))
  chmP2R <- rasterize_canopy(las, res = 1, algorithm = p2r()) # fill voids with p2r interpolations
  chmP2R[is.na(chmP2R[])] <- 0 # still some NAs so replacing NA's by zero
  chmPitFree_voidsP2R <- terra::cover(chmPitFree, chmP2R, values = NA) # put them together

  # Can I use AUTOCROP = TRUE in options below to replace the following 3 lines of code. I.e., crop to chunk extent.
  # rast(chmPitFree_voidsP2R)
  # bbox <- lidR::extent(chunk)
  # chmPitFree_voidsP2R  <- terra::crop(chmPitFree_voidsP2R, bbox)
  
  return(chmPitFree_voidsP2R)
}

opt_chunk_size(ctgNorm) <- 20
opt_chunk_buffer(ctgNorm) <- 2
opt_progress(ctgNorm) <- TRUE
opt_output_files(ctgNorm) <- "D:/Temp/chmNorm_tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"

# Here the autocrop isn't doing what I'm expecting (reducing extent to the chunk extent)
opt <- list(autocrop = TRUE)
myCHM <- catalog_apply(ctgNorm, makeCHM_function, .options = opt)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct and works fine. I can't see any problem. You could add `opt <- list(autocrop = TRUE, automerge = TRUE)`

That being said your function is still very simple (it returns a raster) and you can use `catalog_map` which simplifies the process by automatically reading and cropping.

```r
makeCHM_function = function(las) 
{
  vegetation <- filter_poi(las, (Classification == 3L | Classification == 4L | Classification == 5L) & Z > 0)
  if (is.empty(vegetation))
    return(NULL)
  if (npoints(vegetation) < 3)
    return(NULL)
  chmPitFree <- rasterize_canopy(las, 1, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15), max_edge = c(3, 1.5), subcircle = 0.15))
  chmP2R <- rasterize_canopy(las, res = 1, algorithm = p2r()) # fill voids with p2r interpolations
  chmP2R[is.na(chmP2R[])] <- 0 # still some NAs so replacing NA's by zero
  chmPitFree_voidsP2R <- terra::cover(chmPitFree, chmP2R, values = NA) # put them together
  
  return(chmPitFree_voidsP2R)
}

opt_chunk_size(ctgNorm) <- 20
opt_chunk_buffer(ctgNorm) <- 2
opt_progress(ctgNorm) <- TRUE
opt_output_files(ctgNorm) <- "D:/Temp/chmNorm_tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"

myCHM <- catalog_map(ctgNorm, makeCHM_function)
```

Comment: This code in the answer with catalog_map() works well so I'll go with that. But, for me, my code with autocrop = TRUE still leaves the overlap ... maybe it's my system?

Comment: I don't think so, Why do you think it leaves overlap. In this stage with filename as output it is not easy to see it. So I added `automerge` and the output looks good.

Comment: automerge does work, but my output needs to be tiles. Ideally those tiles are 1 km by 1 km without the buffer. The overlap can be seen in a GIS like ArcPro

Comment: I'll have a look